# dockerのdata領域を減らすには

Tags: centos, docker

CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
Docker version 1.12.6, build 3a094bd/1.12.6

を使っています。
ディスク容量がいっぱいで調べてみるとdockerのdata領域が肥大していました。

```
$ cd /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/
$ ls -l
合計 9966968
-rw------- 1 root root 107374182400  1月 17 17:13 data
-rw------- 1 root root   2147483648  1月 17 17:10 metadata
```

dockerのimagesを削除(docker rmi)したりしているのですが、効果が無いようです。
「docker system prune」もネットで見つけましたが、

```
# docker system prune
docker: 'system' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'.
```

dockerのバージョンが低いせいなのかはわかりませんが、コマンドが無いようです。

dockerのdata領域を減らすにはどうしたらいいのでしょうか。ご存知の方、ご教示お願いします。

Comment: `docker system prune` が利用できないのはご指摘の通りバージョンが古いからで、このコマンドは Docker Engine 1.13 から利用できます。 https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/

Comment: 関連?: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3182

Answer (score 1):

`docker system prune`が、なかったころ、下記のようなコマンドで不要なものを削除していました。

- タグのないイメージの削除

  `docker rmi $(docker images -qf dangling=true)`
- 停止しているコンテナの削除

  `docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)`
- コンテナに紐付いていないボリュームの削除

コンテナに紐付いていないボリュームを削除します。 
**必要なボリュームでもコンテナが立ち上がっていないと削除対象となってしまうので注意が必要です。**

`docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true)`